# python - Eliminar caracteres do final de uma string

Tags: python, string, criptografia

Existe alguma maneira de eliminar caracteres no final de uma string no python?
Por exemplo:
    a = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    B = "ABCDEFGH"

Preciso que a string "a" fique com o mesmo tamanho da "b", isso é possivel?

Preciso delas do mesmo tamanho pra fazer um processo de criptografia, uma seria a key e a outra o plaintext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
 a_cortado = a[:len(b)]
```

Fazendo assim, você estará cortando a string de `a` exatamente no mesmo tamanho de `b`.

Comment: Funcionou perfeito! Muito Obrigado!!!

Comment: Que bom, cara. Se isso resolveu o problema, considere marcar a pergunta como aceita ou votar positivamente :p

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra maneira seria fazendo um fatiamento, fica assim:

```
a_fatiado = (a[0:8])
```

maneira similar a primeira solução apresentada porém sem precisar usar a função 'len'.

Comment: Mas essa é exatamente a mesma solução apresentada na outra resposta. Qual seria esta outra maneira que comentou?

Comment: Que os parêntesis mudam ?

Comment: Uma maneira similar a primeira solução apresentada porém sem precisar usar a função 'len'.